# What "'QSqlQuery' is deprecated" warning means?

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

I have a DB class with several methods. Normally I use them like:

```
QSqlQuery DB::myfunc(){
  QSqlQuery query;
  ...

  return query;
}
```

I realized i am creating a `QSqlQuery` object in all methods so I created it in header as private member and want to use same `query` variable in all my methods. But I am getting:

```
'QSqlQuery' is deprecated: QSqlQuery is not meant to be copied. Use move construction instead.
:30:5: note: 'QSqlQuery' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
```

warning when i did this. Anything wrong if i use it like that?

Creating QSqlQuery variable everytime in methods work without any warning.

Comment: "Deprecated" means that it still exists but is scheduled for removal in a future version of the library and that you should start using something else instead. Check the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the class is not deprecated but its copy constructor is. See [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqlquery-obsolete.html).
What you want to do is move the object, not copy it, like so:

```
return std::move(query);
```

Comment: Which approach is better do you know?

Comment: I mean, creating a single ```QSqlQuery query``` variable in header and using it in all methods that i have and returning it as ```return std::move(query);``` VS creating ```QSqlQuery query``` in  all methods as local object.

Comment: It is not one versus the other, it is both things together. The method in your function creates a local variable `query` and I am saying you should change your `return` statement to use `std::move(...)`. And no, do not use a global `query` variable; that is too limiting, even if you declare it to be 1 per thread (and there would be no need to write functions to return it if it was available everywhere anyway).